# Error in KNN 'train' and 'class' have different lengths, cl length =1

Tags: r, knn

Good day

I'm getting and error trying to fit a KNN model. I created a test and train dataset as follows:

```
train <- bank_norm[1:32950, ]
test <- bank_norm[32951:41188, ]
train_labels <- bank[1:32950, 1]
bpredict <- knn(train, test, train_labels, 203)
```

To replicate, the two files are on this link:
[Box Folder with two datasets to replicate][1]

```
bank <- read_csv("~/R/bank.csv")
bank_norm <- read_csv("~/R/bank_norm.csv")
```

then execute the code to create train and test and fit the model. 
Any idea what could be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add minimal reproducible example while asking question. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: There are many different implementations of knn.  Which one are you using?  Please include your `library` statement in your code.